# Sharing of standard object according to role

Tags: sharing, data, roles, visibility, standard

I have a scenario where i have 3 roles in org , owner ,supervisor and associates .Owner is like CEO, supervisor reports to owner and associate reports to supervisor. I need to make sure CEO of one company does not see data from CEO of another company and the same goes with supervisor and associates .The data here is in leads, account , opportunity and contact objects which are all standard objects . How can i make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Give a different profile for different CEO's. And give the basic access I.e CRUD operations on profile. For standard objects, Grant Access Using Hierarchies option is enabled. So, the data of subordinate is accessible for the superior. Follow the same for rest 2 roles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rk_cloud for the answer. I still feel this might not work as even members from different company will have the same profile . As we cannot keep increasing the profiles. I feel we might have to introduce territory management here.